# Банально не могу запустить программу. Ошибка в компилировании

Tags: java

Изначально в текстовом документе

```
public class MyFirstApp { 
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println(«Hello World!»); 
        } 
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку

```
C:\Users\Степан\Desktop\Java>javac MyFirstApp.java
MyFirstApp.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u00ab'
                System.out.println(┬лHello World!┬╗);
                                    ^
MyFirstApp.java:3: error: ';' expected
                System.out.println(┬лHello World!┬╗);
                                                ^
MyFirstApp.java:3: error: illegal character: '\u00bb'
                System.out.println(┬лHello World!┬╗);
                                                  ^
MyFirstApp.java:3: error: not a statement
                System.out.println(┬лHello World!┬╗);
                                             ^
```

4 errors

Comment: Строки обрамляются символом `"`.

Answer (score 1):

```java
public class MyFirstApp { 
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!"); // Кавычки 
        } 
}
```